# NodeJS: How do I get a correct encrypted result?

Tags: node.js

I am writing the DES encryption code using NodeJS.

According to the DES algorithm, the result should be like this,

```
* http://www.unsw.adfa.edu.au/~lpb/src/DEScalc/DEScalc.html

An example DES test value, taken from
"H. Katzan, The Standard Data Encryption Algorithm, pp75-94, Petrocelli Books Inc., New York, 1977" is:

Key:        5B5A57676A56676E (HEX)
Plaintext:  675A69675E5A6B5A (HEX)
Ciphertext: 974AFFBF86022D1F (HEX)
```

However, my code prints somewhat different values.

```
var assert = require("assert");
var crypto = require("crypto");

var plaintext = new Buffer( '675A69675E5A6B5A', 'hex' ).toString( 'binary' );
var key = new Buffer( '5B5A57676A56676E', 'hex' ).toString( 'binary' );

var cipher = crypto.createCipher( 'des-ecb', key );
var c = cipher.update( plaintext, 'binary', 'hex' );
c += cipher.final( 'hex' );

console.log( c );
```

What should I fix in the upper code?

Answer (score 5):

5B5A57676A56676E is the Key, not password.

```
var crypto = require("crypto");
var plaintext = new Buffer( '675A69675E5A6B5A', 'hex' ).toString( 'binary' );
console.log("plian:"+plaintext);
var key = new Buffer( '5B5A57676A56676E', 'hex' );
var iv = new Buffer(8);
iv.fill(0);
var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv("des", key, iv);
cipher.setAutoPadding(false);
var c = cipher.update( plaintext, 'binary', 'hex' );
c+=cipher.final('hex' );
console.log(c);
```